# Apache Alias causing .htaccess rewrite to fail

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I'm using AMPPS with an alias so my local site can run from it's local project folder on a USB and be accessed from `http://localhost/myproject` without having to copy it over to `Applications/AMPPS/www`.

However, this is causing a number of issues. Most notably, my .htaccess file containing my URL rewrite rules is not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/\.]+)/?$ /portfolio/$1.php [L]
```

Basically, this takes the URL like:

```
localhost/myproject/portfolio/somesite/
```

And searches for:

```
localhost/myproject/portfolio/somesite.php
```

Except now, when I try and click any of my rewritten links, I'm confronted with this message:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /portfolio/somesite.php was not found on this server.
```

Previously this rule has worked when I wasn't using an alias, yet now it's completely broken. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `RewriteBase` and remove leading slash from your target:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/

RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/.]+)/?$ portfolio/$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Excellent, this works. But what do I do when I need to upload my files to my server? Do I have to manually change the .htaccess file every time?

Comment: Do you not have `/myproject` directory on server?

Comment: Well, not really. It's at the root level, not inside a directory.